# How do I catch infinite scroll last index

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get last index in data-table on page. But this table using infinite scroll.Therefore every scroll event mixing last index. How can I control this situration.

```
str_index=findElement("//*[@id=\"Table\"]/div/div[2]/div/span/span",Path.xPath).getText();
    index=Integer.parseInt(str_index)-1;
```

str_index= Table info for how many items is showing.And I get this value for using xPath.

```
WebElement last=findElement("//*[@id=\"Table\"]/div/div[1]/div/cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport/div[1]/table/tbody/tr["+index+"]/td[18]",Path.xPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I fix the problem. I use this:

```
WebElement last=findElement("//*[@id=\"Table\"]/div/div[1]/div/cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[18]",Path.xPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the bottom of the document:

```
public void scrollToBottom() {
     jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
}
```